# Performing cluster analysis in R with Point Datasets

Tags: r, point, clustering

I am a R-Beginner, but I want to use it for some spatial statistics. I want to check the relation between the occurrence of ill persons and the existence of water in a area of interest. To give you a more specific use case, I've created some example datasets:

- **[Table - Persons](http://pastebin.com/WET3jmks)**
- **[Table - City](http://pastebin.com/emnKiGJp)**
- **[Table - Water](http://pastebin.com/5saUPKbb)**

Firstly I want to plot them in a map including a basemap. This already works!

```
persons_dataframe = read.csv("persons.csv", header = TRUE)
city_dataframe = read.csv("city.csv", header = TRUE)
water_dataframe = read.csv("water.csv", header = TRUE)
# plot them on a map
# load used packages
library(RgoogleMaps)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sp)

persons_ggplot2 <- persons_dataframe
city_ggplot2 <- city_dataframe
water_ggplot2 <- water_dataframe
gc <- geocode('new york, usa')
center <- as.numeric(gc)  
G <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = center, color = 'bw', scale = 1, zoom = 10, maptype = "terrain", frame=T), extent="device")
G1 <- G + geom_point(aes(x=POINT_X, y=POINT_Y ),data=city_dataframe, shape = 22, color="black", fill = "yellow", size = 4) + geom_point(aes(x=POINT_X, y=POINT_Y ),data=persons_dataframe, shape = 8, color="red", size=2.5) + geom_point(aes(x=POINT_X, y=POINT_Y ),data=water_ggplot2, color="blue", size=1)
plot(G1)
```

This has the following output:
[image: R Plot]

No I want to create something like a cluster map. I've already looked for some useful packages and I've ended with the packages *SpatialEpi* and *DCluser*. Both provide some functions, which might be useful.

But at this point I don't know, how to proceed. Some open questions:

1. Is it right that I need polygons to cluster the dataset? I've read it in the [SpatialEpi pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SpatialEpi/SpatialEpi.pdf) but I only have these point datasets.
2. Additionally I don't know, if the fact that all points are located on only three locations might be a problem?!

Do you have a suggestions how to continue with my work?

Comment: Is there anyone, who has an idea?

Comment: which point layer do you want to do clustering (person, city,..)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with [**mclust**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html) (model based clustering). To cluster the Persons table into two seperate clusters.

**R Script**

```
require(mclust)
require(sp)

data =read.csv(file = "person.txt")

data.xy <- cbind(data$POINT_X, data$POINT_Y) 

patternBIC <- mclustBIC(data.xy) 

patternModel <- summary(patternBIC, data.xy)
print(patternModel)

n <- patternModel$G
cond_probs <- lapply(1:n, function(i) patternModel$z[,i])
names(cond_probs) <- paste0("cond_prob", 1:n)

q <- quantile(patternModel$uncertainty, probs = c(0.75, 0.95))
q7595 <- sapply(patternModel$uncertainty, function(u){
  r <- if (u <= q[1]) 1 else 0
  if(u <= q[2] && r == 0) r <- 2
  if(u > q[2] && r == 0) r <- 3
  stopifnot(r != 0)
  r - 1
})

result <- data.frame(data,
          cluster = patternModel$classification,
          class_uncert = patternModel$uncertainty,
          sym_ucert=q7595,
          cond_probs)

par("mfrow"=c(1,1))
plot(result$POINT_X,result$POINT_Y,col=result$cluster)
```

**persons.txt** looks like:

```
city,ill,computer,POINT_X,POINT_Y
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,1,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,1,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City A,yes,0,-73.996786,40.720813
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,1,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City B,yes,0,-74.172237,40.732196
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
City C,yes,0,-74.197274,40.625130
```

Make sure both files are in the same directory and you set the working directory to that of your R script